# Обращение к элементам формы из класса

Tags: c#, классы

Не могу обратиться к элементу формы через класс, что только не перепробовал, все равно не работает

Comment: Что значит «обратиться через класс»? Расшифруйте.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что элемент формы объявлен как private или protected член. Вам необходимо в коде формы добавить свойство для доступа к значения элемента (или самому элементу, если требуется), например:

```
class MyForm
{
    private TextBox txtFirstName;

    public string FirstName { get { return txtFirstName.Text;} }
}
```